# Dynamically adding to an existing key value pair in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Ok, so 8 months into Ruby Hashes are still proving somewhat of an enigma.

I pull 10 records from the database, each with its own category field. Many of the records with share the same category, so I want them grouped by their categories in a hash.

I understand that the Key's are always unique, which is what makes a Hash a Hash. What I am struggling to do is add values to the existing key in the hash.

```
def self.categorise_events
    hash = {}
    self.limit(10).map do |event|
        if hash.key?(event.event_type) #check if the key already exists
            hash[event.event_type][event] #add the event record to that key
        else
            hash[event.event_type] = event #create the key if it doesn't exist and add the record 
        end
    end
    hash
end
```

This is more of a gist of what I am trying to achieve. I've had other compositions which have been closer but still not quite doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is always uniq. So if you want to add values to a key, that value should be Array.

In this situation you can use `group_by`. Try

```
hash = self.limit(10).group_by{|e| e.event_type}
```

It returns a Hash whose keys are event_type and values are Array of records.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to an existing hash like

```
hash[key] = value
```

but in your case, your value is a collection of values, so it's an array

```
hash[key] = []
hash[key] << value
```

so you can add to an existing group with

```
unless hash.key?(event.event_type)
  hash[event.event_type] = []
end

hash[event.event_type] << event
```

Now, this can be accomplished with the builtin method `#group_by` as seen on the [documentations](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by). But in your case, because it's using ActiveRecord, you can consider using `#group` to group records using SQL and greatly improving the performance of the grouping

```
self.limit(10).group(:event_type)
```

Check out the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group).

Comment: than k you, your answer helped a great deal with understanding

Comment: It's better to do `hash[key] ||= []` than `hash[key] = []` : the former is equivalent to `hash[key] = (hash[key] || [])` and will only set it to an empty array if it doesn't exist already.  If you do `hash[key] = []` you risk wiping out what you had in there already.